# syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Tags: laravel-8, php-7.4, laravel-jetstream

I'am using **php 7.4.27**, **laravel framework 8.83.7** and installed **Laravel Jetstream**.
*Login* & *Register* can show. After registered, Then an error notification appears in Laravel:
*syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'*
and in code line 12 :

```
<?php $component = $__env->getContainer()->make(Illuminate\View\AnonymousComponent::class, ['view' => 'jetstream::components.dropdown-link','data' => ['href' => $href,'@click.prevent' => $@clickPrevent]]); ?>
```

I won't update to php 8. What should i do?

=====edited=====
[image: complete error]

composer.json file :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/jetstream": "^2.7",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "livewire/livewire": "^2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Comment: Show us the **complete** error stack trace, please.

Comment: im done edited my quest bro @steven7mwesigwa

Comment: You can get the complete error stack trace either from your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file or the browser's **Network -> Response** tabs.  Currently, you're only showing us small bits of the stack trace.

Comment: Sounds like there's a bug in the library, causing it to generate invalid PHP code - specifically, it's tried to generate a variable name dynamically without checking the name is valid, and ended up with `$@clickPrevent`. I suggest raising a bug with the library author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Explanation:

The issue comes from the fact that the compiled view version under `storage/framework/views`  is failing to evaluate `$@clickPrevent`.

```sh
<?php $component = $__env->getContainer()->make(Illuminate\View\AnonymousComponent::class, ['view' => 'jetstream::components.dropdown-link','data' => ['href' => $href,'@click.prevent' => $@clickPrevent]]); ?>
```

This has nothing to do with your current PHP version.

##### Solution:

I managed to locally reproduce the issue. <s>Here is how I solved it.</s>

##### Steps:

1. <s>Publish the Jetstream Livewire components.</s>

   <s>*Command:*</s>

   `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views`
2. <s>Open the file `resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/switchable-team.blade.php`</s>

   <s>In the file contents,</s>

   <s>*Instead of:*</s>

   ```php
    <x-dynamic-component :component="$component" href="#" @click.prevent="$root.submit();"> ❌
   ```

   <s>*Use this:*</s>

   ```php
    <x-dynamic-component :component="$component" href="#"> ✅
   ```

##### Disclaimer:

*Note that this is a temporary solution. Everything works fine for me. As lamented by [@IMSoP in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805796/syntax-error-unexpected-expecting-variable-t-variable-or-or?noredirect=1#comment126896231_71805796), I'm afraid it may affect some unknown functionality. I've opened an issue against the library here:*

[switchable-team.blade.php compiled Jetstream component throwing an error: syntax error, unexpected token "@", expecting variable or "{" or "$"](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/1036)

---

##### Update 10th/April/2022:

Another *"more stable"* solution stated by [@fabpl](https://github.com/fabpl) on the opened Github issue:

> I think it's the same bug like [[2.x] Fix parse error caused by alpine
> shorthand on dynamic-component
> #1032](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/pull/1032)
>
> Try to replace `@click` with `x-on:click`
>
> - https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/1036#issuecomment-1094253898

##### Addendum:

The issue seems to have been [introduced in `laravel/jetstream v2.7.2`](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/releases/tag/v2.7.2). More specifically [Use Alpine's @click.prevent for switching teams](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/pull/1027).

The good news is that this has been [resolved beginning from `laravel/jetstream v2.7.3` onwards](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/releases/tag/v2.7.3). More specifically [[2.x] Fix parse error caused by alpine shorthand on dynamic-component](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/pull/1032/files).

> I just tagged v2.7.3 which should fix this. Thanks all
>
> - https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/issues/1036#issuecomment-1094332998

Hence, you may simply just upgrade your Jetstream version to `v2.7.3` to get the fix. I.e:

*Command:*

`composer update laravel/jetstream:2.7.3`

*Sample Output*:

```sh
PS C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\SteveContents\GITHUB\Laravel-8.83.7\laravel-8.83.7> composer update laravel/jetstream:2.7.3
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Upgrading laravel/jetstream (v2.7.2 => v2.7.3)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Downloading laravel/jetstream (v2.7.3)
  - Downloading laravel/jetstream (v2.7.3)
  - Downloading laravel/jetstream (v2.7.3)
  - Downloading laravel/jetstream (v2.7.3)
  - Upgrading laravel/jetstream (v2.7.2 => v2.7.3): Extracting archive
...
```